# Dual fixture ( Stencil, SMT carrier...)

Tags: surface-mount, dual, stencil

I have an output upgrade project on SMT, part of which is dual fixture (2 sides BOT & TOP on the same side).
So is there anyone here with experience with this? Can u give me some advice on this?
[image]

Comment: Does this method really work?

Comment: I’m having trouble visualising your question. Do you want to know how to mount smt on both sides? A picture might assist.

Comment: Actually, this is just an idea, you can imagine it as follows

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: @Hearth Seeking advice from someone who has experience making a similar product

Comment: @JonathanChuUHAN Similar to *what*?